# Indexing Elements in a list of tuples

Tags: python, indexing

I have the following list, created by using the zip function on two separate lists of numbers:

```
[(20, 6),
(21, 4),
(22, 4),
(23, 2),
(24, 8),
(25, 3),
(26, 4),
(27, 4),
(28, 6),
(29, 2),
(30, 8)]
```

I would like to know if there is a way to iterate through this list and receive the number on the LHS that corresponds to the maximum value on the RHS, i.e. in this case I would like to get 24 and 30, which both have a value of 8 (the max value of the RHS). I have tried:

```
## get max of RHS 
max_1 = max([i[1] for i in data])
## for max of LHR, index this location
## on RHS column 
number = [i[1] for i in data].index(max_1)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you still have the second list? Then for `max_1`, you could just take the max of that list. Simpler than to get it from the already zipped lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After:

```
max_1 = max([i[1] for i in data])
```

Try:

```
>>> number = [i[0] for i in data if i[1]==max_1]
>>> number
[24, 30]
```

Comment: You should show where `max_1` is coming from. Also, unpacking `i` may produce a more readable list comprehension.

Comment: You don't really need the brackets in your call to `max()`.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, it worked. max_1 is just the max value of the RHS column